# Column chaotic reorder in ArrayFire using other than CPU backends

Tags: arrayfire

I have multiple arrays as separate fields, when I join them together, somehow an specific column gets switched with another column strangely.

All columns have proper data on their own, but shuffled when joined. I also used af::eval but didn't fix the issue. And notice that this is completely random, sometimes if I comment the print lines it works! (It's OK with the CPU backend)

[image]
Info: ArrayFire v3.9.0 using unified backend as CUDA.